# In Unity is there a way to render something simple during the frame?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, rendering

In Unity is there a way to render something simple during the frame, instead of waiting until unity renders it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about rendering GL primitives, there is the [`GL` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) which can be called from [`OnRenderObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderObject.html), [`OnPostRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.OnPostRender.html) or [`OnRenderImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.OnRenderImage.html).

But with a question this vague, it is impossible to give a more direct answer than that.

Comment: for example, if my scene freezes and fps is very low, can I  have something moving independently? btw, is GL only for pay version?

Comment: @craft000 No. If your scene freezes or you have low framerate, how do you expect Unity to render anything else? It can't decide to suddenly render faster by magic. As for GL calls, no they are available in free edition